# Creating Model in Laravel 4.2

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-4

I am using MySQL Database. How can I make "Model" in Laravel 4.2? Do I need to use migration? Please guide me.

I have tried following:

```
php artisan migrate:make Post
```

on my command prompt.
Also I have added the following codes in my migration.

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('posts',function (Blueprint $table){
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('title');
   $table->text('body');
   });
}
```

Do I need to add something else. Please Guide me.

Answer (score 1):

A model doens't have to represent a database table. I think you mix up migrations, tables and models here.

A migration creates an table in your database when you execute

```
php artisan migrate
```

in your console.

The table has to get an Model if you want to use it in your Controllers, you have to create this one yourself. If I remember correctly, there is a folder in Laravel 4.2 called Models, create a file there called Posts.php and fill it with the information needed for using your table. I strongly advise you to read the following docs about Eloquent and Models in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Besides that, consider using Laravel 5 instead of 4.